# How do I set Jackson parser features when using json4s?

Tags: scala, jackson, json4s

I am receiving the following error while attempting to parse JSON with json4s:

```
Non-standard token 'NaN': enable JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS to allow
```

How do I enable this feature?

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/accept answers if they helped you! You'll be more likely to get help in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) object is named `mapper`:

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
// Configure NaN here
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS, true)

...

val json = ... //Get your json
val imported = mapper.readValue(json, classOf[Thing])  // Thing being whatever class you're importing to.
```

Comment: Hm... I think my error happens when I read the JSON document though:

    val json = parse(jsonString)

Comment: @arosca I'm afraid without more context/code I can't entirely see the relation.

Answer (score 2):

@Nathaniel Ford, thanks for setting me on the right path!

I ended up looking at the source code for the parse() method (which is what I should have done in the first place). This works:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.Json4sScalaModule

val jsonString = """{"price": NaN}"""

val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
// Configure NaN here
mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS, true)
mapper.registerModule(new Json4sScalaModule)

val json = mapper.readValue(jsonString, classOf[JValue])
```

Answer (score 2):

While the answers above are still correct, what should be amended is, that since Jackson 2.10 `JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS` is deprecated.

The sustainable way for configuring correct `NaN` handling is the following:

```scala
val mapper = JsonMapper.builder().enable(JsonReadFeature.ALLOW_NON_NUMERIC_NUMBERS).build();
// now your parsing
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, as I wanted to migrate. As this is a "read" feature, do you happen to know if this also affects writing to json?

Comment: Hey @Vankog, yes I know it and no, it does not affect writing. :-)